# Using Jaccard Coefficient for measuring string similarity

Tags: similarity, information-retrieval

I got a test and a training dataset which should be used for string similarity measurement. Here I have given few lines of the dataset,

```
Brandon Bass ||| what the hell is Brandon bass thinking ||| Brandon Bass Has 5 Personal Fouls ||| False
Sac ||| Congrats to Sac Kings fans ||| why yall forcing the kings to stay in sac town smh ||| False
Stella ||| hello Stella can you follow me please ||| STELLA DO U HATE ME ||| False


The data file has 50 entries of the form 
TOPIC ||| TWEET_SENT_1 ||| TWEET_SENT_2 ||| HAVE_SIMILAR_MEANING
```

TOPIC – Twitter topic

```
TWEET_SENT_1 – Tweet sentence 1
TWEET_SENT_2 – Tweet sentence 2
HAVE_SIMILAR_MEANING – a binary label (True – two sentences are similar, false – two sentences are not similar) assigned by a human annotator
```

We need to divide the data set into two: training set (35 samples) and test set (15 samples) and have to use the training set for parameter tuning of the algorithms. And test with the test set using the best tuned parameter.

If the algorithm is Jaccard Coefficient

how can I perform this task? Can someone please let me know the approach that I can use.

Answer (score 1):

Jaccard similarity is a measure of how two sets (of n-grams in your case) are similar. There is no "tuning" to be done here, except for the threshold at which you decide that two strings are similar or not.

For example if you have 2 strings `abcde` and `abdcde` it works as follow :

```
ngrams (n=2) :  'abcde' & 'abdcde'
   ab bc cd de dc bd
A  1  1  1  1  0  0
B  1  0  1  1  1  1
```

J(A, B) = (A∩B) / (A∪B)

J(A, B) = (3 / 6) =  0.5

There is also the Jaccard distance which captures the dissimilarity between two sets, and is calculated by taking `one` minus the Jaccard coeeficient (in this case, `1 - 0.5 = 0.5`)

So, for you problem, I would use the training set with the labels in order to define the proper threshold for which your strings are considered similar/dissimilar.